# 'GPIBInstrument' object has no attribute 'ask'

Tags: python, gpib

I am now using python to get data from lock in amplifer with GPIB and met a error report to get data. The lock in amplifier is SR865A.

```
import pyvisa as visa
import time,string
import random


class device:
    def __init__(self,visa_code='GPIB0::8::INSTR'):
       # print("in init")

        #self.device=visa.instrument(add)
        rm = visa.ResourceManager()

        self.device=rm.open_resource(visa_code)
#get data    
    def get_all(self):
        return self.device.ask('SNAP? 0,1,2,3')
        
                          
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    add="GPIB0::14"
    lockin=device(add)
    #f = open('test.dat','wb');
    data=lockin.get_all()
    x=float(data.split(',')[0])
    y=float(data.split(',')[1])
    r=float(data.split(',')[2])
    theta=float(data.split(',')[3])
```

Error report; AttributeError: 'GPIBInstrument' object has no attribute 'ask'

Comment: Use `query` instead of `ask`, i. e. `return self.device.query("SNAP? 0,1,2,3")`.

Comment: When I run into attribute errors such as this, my strategy is to check what attributes are available on the object. This can be achieved by printing the output after passing an object into the `dir()` function in Python. In your example, it would be `dir(self.device)`.

Comment: @alexschu98 I used query instead of ask. But here comes another error:
pyvisa.errors.visaioerror: vi_error_nlisteners (-1073807265): no listeners condition is detected (both nrfd and ndac are deasserted)
I have already checked that my communication address is correct.

Comment: Is your device maybe in "local" mode and you have to set it to remote control manually? Also is it listed in the resource manager (`rm.list_resources()`)?

Comment: @alexschu98 I "solved" problem. The interaction is fine and most commands can work only this "SNAP? i,j,k" doesn't work. This command is to Query multiple lock-in parameters at once. I just removed it and used other command to get data one by one. But anyway I still don't know why this command doesn't work.

Comment: Strange issue, I do not see any reason for it not to work. However good you figured it out, sorry I wasn't that much of a help.